# Recursive Function to read every Node of Xml file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, recursion

I want a code to read xml file and get all its node values recursively and check the level of nodes too.print every node and if level of node is 2 or more than 2 print a text field in front of node name. but i am not getting any node value.thank you in advance

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> INSERT VALUES OF THE GIVEN PHRASE IDS : </head>
<!-- <head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head> -->
<body>

<form name="form" action="xmlform.php" method="post">

<?php

echo ("<pre>");

$file="english.xml";

if(file_exists($file))
{
  $xml=simplexml_load_file("$file") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml as $xmlRoot => $value) {
    $lvl=0;
    $xmlNode=$value->children();

    //if(is_null($value->children())) {echo "true";}exit();
   echo '<input type="text" name="xmlNode" value="'.$xmlNode.'" > <br>';

  function makeAFieldForNode($xmlNode, $lvl) {
    if ($lvl >= 2) {
         echo '<input type="text" value="" name="value"> <br>';
    } 
        $newLvl =   $lvl++;
        foreach ( $xmlNode->children() as $xn) {
        makeAFieldForNode($xN, $newLvl);  
     }
} 

makeAFieldForNode();

}

}

echo ("</pre>");


?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

english.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" id="123" value="" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
           <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

i want a form in output if u see above xml file i want some thing like this

```
catalog
     product
      123  (123 is id and text field for value infront of it )
                catalog-item
                     size
                         color_swatch
                          color (color id id of color_swatch and text field for value)
```

so if i add some value on submission button i can generate a new xml file like the one which already exist but with new values of ids of respective elements. For right now i am trying to generate that form with all elements of xml file. I want a dynamic code so whatever xml file it is . my code should read every element and read it and give id and text field for value.I hope you are getting my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull with the position of increment operator :

```
$newLvl =   $lvl++;
```

`$newLvl` will get the value of `$lvl` **before** increment (see http://3v4l.org/aj7t3)

In your case, you don't even need a new variable, just do `$lvl++` and use it in your function call :

```
$lvl++;
foreach ( $xmlNode->children() as $xn) {
    makeAFieldForNode($xN, $lvl);  
}
```

Edit : to make a more complete answer, I'd need to know what you mean by :

> node values

and

> print every node

as some of your nodes doesn't have `value` attribute (`product` or `size` for example).

If you could provide an example of the output you want to get, that would help to understand your need.

---

== Edit : add script ==

Try this : http://3v4l.org/UspVk

Comment: i want a form in output if u see above xml file i want some thing like this 
catalog
     product
      123  (123 is id and text field for value infront of it )
                catalog-item
                     size
                         color_swatch
                          color (color id id of color_swatch and text field for value)

Comment: @RozeenaIbrahim Added a link to a possible solution that you can test